How to render a Grid.js table in save.js for a custom WordPress Gutenberg block?
I'm working on a custom Gutenberg block in WordPress where I need to render a dynamic table using the Grid.js library. I've managed to set up the table in the edit.js file for the block's editor view. Now, I want to render the same table on the frontend using the save.js file. However, I'm unsure how to properly implement this in save.js.
